# When does superdiagonal matrix have a single Jordan block

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Let $A$ be the superdiagonal matrix given by $A=(a_{ij})$ where $a_{i,i+1}=r_i$ are nonzero entries and all the other entries are $0$. When is $A$ similar to a single Jordan block with eigenvalue $0$ in term of the entries?

 I know that $A$ is nilpotent, so its only eigenvalue is $\lambda=0$.

Comment: The number of Jordan blocks for such a matrix is proportional to the number of eigenvectors, which, given how we can rearrange the rows and columns, is  one plus the number of $a_{i,i+1}$ that are $0$.

Comment: Yes, provided that in a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ all $a_{i, i+1}$ are nonzero, this matrix is similar to a single Jordan block. This is because the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $X^n$ (why?)